# Why are all "meta.sitenamehere.stackexchange.com" sites HTTP-only?

Tags: discussion, meta, per-site-meta, ssl, http

Why are all `meta.sitenamehere.stackexchange.com` sites HTTP-only?

For example, https://unix.stackexchange.com/ supports HTTPS, but its meta site https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ does not support HTTPS. Placing HTTPS into the URL just redirects you to the HTTP version.

This does not affect StackExchange sites with their own domains, however. https://askubuntu.com/ supports HTTPS, and its meta site https://meta.askubuntu.com/ also supports HTTPS, unlike the meta site on a stackexchange.com subdomain like Unix SE.

Comment: This is mostly the same problem as the duplicate though I'm mostly asking about the fact that it is this way rather than reporting an error message.

Comment: Why? Because implementing HTTPS support across all the meta sites is very complicated, and Stack Exchange is still in the process of doing that. It's mentioned in [Nick's blog post](http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/): "meta.*.stackexchange.com? Damn. Can’t do that. You can’t have a wildcard of that form - at least not one supported by most major browsers, which means effectively it’s not an option"